# Find the Standard Deviation from a CSV File using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file named 'salaries.csv' The content of the files is as follows:

```
City,Job,Salary
Delhi,Doctors,500
Delhi,Lawyers,400
Delhi,Plumbers,100
London,Doctors,800
London,Lawyers,700
London,Plumbers,300
Tokyo,Doctors,900
Tokyo,Lawyers,800
Tokyo,Plumbers,400
Lawyers,Doctors,300
Lawyers,Lawyers,400
Lawyers,Plumbers,500
Hong Kong,Doctors,1800
Hong Kong,Lawyers,1100
Hong Kong,Plumbers,1000
Moscow,Doctors,300
Moscow,Lawyers,200
Moscow,Plumbers,100
Berlin,Doctors,800
Berlin,Plumbers,900
Paris,Doctors,900
Paris,Lawyers,800
Paris,Plumbers,500
Paris,Dog catchers,400
```

I need to print the standard deviation of salaries of each profession.
This is an older version of Python. Cannot use statistics and numpy.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import math
import csv
with open("salaries.csv") as f:
  def average(f): return sum(f) * 1.0 / len(f)
variance = map(lambda x: (x - avg)**2, f)
standard_deviation = math.sqrt(average(variance))
print standard_deviation
```

Can someone help me, I am a newbie to the field of python.

```
Error : TypeError('argument 2 to map() must support iteration',)
```

The output should be

`Plumbers 311
Lawyers 286
Doctors 448`

Comment: Show us your code and show us the error you received.

Comment: Un-indent `count += 1` and everything after that. Whitespace and indentation matters in Python. You have too much.

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey Can you help me with a smaller code for this program. I know that surely can be done. Just not working out for me.

Comment: Why would you want your code shorter?

Comment: @wwii Because, I need a simpler code than this. Its an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the details per profession, create a dictionary instead:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import math

def get_stats(profession, salaries):   
  n = float(len(salaries))
  mean = sum(salaries)/n
  stdev = 0
  for value in salaries:
    stdev += (value - mean)**2
  stdev = math.sqrt(stdev/(n))
  print profession, min(salaries), max(salaries), mean, stdev

with open('salaries.csv') as f:
  f.readline()
  # Create the list of salaries 
  salaries = {} 
  for line in f.readlines():
    country, profession, value = line.split(',')
    value = int(value.strip())
    profession = profession.strip()
    if salaries.has_key(profession):
        salaries[profession].append(value)
    else:
        salaries[profession] = [value]
  for k,v in salaries.items():
    get_stats(k,v)
```

Comment: NameError("global name 'sqrt' is not defined",)

Comment: I'm running the code and it works. Please check the indentation and the import statement.

Comment: Thanks, removing the sqrt and putting 
` stdev = (stdev/(n))**0.5`

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1. There are built-in functions in Python to get the length, the minimum value and the maximum value of a list of numbers ( `len`, `min` and `max`, respectively).
2. If you're using Python>=3.4.0 there is a module called `statistics` that helps you calculate the means and the standard deviation of a list.

Create stdev.py file next to salaries.csv.

```
from statistics import mean, stdev
f = open("salaries.csv", 'r')

# Remove the first line City,Job,Salary
f.readline()

# Create the list of salaries 
salaries = []
for line in f.readlines():
  # After splitting the line, take the last element, remove extra spaces and cast it to int.
  value = int(line.split(',')[-1].strip())
  # Add the value to the salaries list.
  salaries.append(value)
# min and max return the minimum and the maximum value of the list.
print min(salaries), max(salaries)   
print mean(salaries), stdev(salaries)  
f.close()
```

For Python 2.x:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from math import sqrt
with open('salaries.csv') as f:
  f.readline()
  # Create the list of salaries 
  salaries = []
  for line in f.readlines():
    value = int(line.split(',')[-1].strip())
    salaries.append(value)
  print min(salaries), max(salaries)   
  n = float(len(salaries))
  mean = sum(salaries)/n
  stdev = 0
  for value in salaries:
    stdev += (value - mean)**2
  stdev = sqrt(stdev/(n))
  print mean, stdev
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.4
Its an online compiler that are using to submit the codes. 
Can you write a code for Python <2.5

Comment: `from __future__ import with_statement

from math import sqrt

import csv

...
# Instead of print mean(salaries), stdev(salaries)
with open("salaries.csv") as f:

n = float(len(f))
mean = sum(f)/n
stdev = 0
for value in salaries:
  stdev += (value - mean)**2
stdev = sqrt(stdev/(n-1))
print mean, stdev`

Comment: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('', 4, 1, '...\n'))

Comment: The with statement doesn't work like that. `with` handles the file so you don't need to worry about closing it afterwards, but it doesn't parse the file for you. You'll still need to parse all the lines in salaries.csv and create the list of salaries.

Comment: from math import sqrt
import csv

n = float(len('salaries.csv'))
mean = sum('salaries.csv')/n
stdev = 0
for value in salaries:
  stdev += (value - mean)**2
stdev = sqrt(stdev/(n-1))
print mean, stdev

Comment: TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'",)

Comment: getting wrong output with your code.

100 1800
384.458022435

Comment: Added the sample output in the post

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary for each file and map a list of salaries to professions. Then make your calculations at the end, either with your own functions or numpy.mean and numpy.std:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from numpy import std, mean
>>>
>>> profession_to_salaries = defaultdict(list)
>>>
>>> with open('salaries.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...   reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...   for row in reader:
...     profession_to_salaries[row['Job']].append(float(row['Salary']))
...
>>> for profession, salaries in profession_to_salaries.items():
...   print profession, min(salaries), max(salaries), mean(salaries), std(salaries)
...
Plumbers 100.0 1000.0 475.0 311.24748995
Lawyers 200.0 1100.0 628.571428571 286.427680797
Dog catchers 400.0 400.0 400.0 0.0
Doctors 300.0 1800.0 787.5 448.434777866
```

---

*for python 2.4:*

```
>>> from __future__ import with_statement
>>> import csv
>>>
>>> def mean(lst):
...     return sum(lst) * 1.0 / len(lst)
...
>>> def variance(lst):
...     m = mean(lst)
...     return [ (x - m) ** 2 for x in lst ]
...
>>> def std(lst):
...     return mean(variance(lst))**0.5
...
>>> profession_to_salaries = {}
>>>
>>> with open('salaries.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         profession = row['Job']
...         if not profession in profession_to_salaries:
...             profession_to_salaries[row['Job']] = []
...         profession_to_salaries[row['Job']].append(float(row['Salary']))
...
>>> for profession, salaries in profession_to_salaries.items():
...     print profession, min(salaries), max(salaries), mean(salaries), std(salaries)
...
Plumbers 100.0 1000.0 475.0 311.24748995
Lawyers 200.0 1100.0 628.571428571 286.427680797
Dog catchers 400.0 400.0 400.0 0.0
Doctors 300.0 1800.0 787.5 448.434777866
```

Comment: IndentationError('unexpected indent', ('', 8, 3, "   with open('salaries.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:\n"))

What should I do?

Comment: ImportError('No module named numpy',)

Comment: Its an online compiler which uses older version. Any help?

Comment: If you can't install numpy provide your own mean and std dev functions. This might help: http://calebmadrigal.com/standard-deviation-in-python/

Comment: Editing the posts. Can you check it now.

Comment: You should be posting new questions rather than editing your question.

Comment: Yes, but that require another 90 minutes to wait. Kindly help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import math
import csv


def std_dev(v):
    avg = sum([int(sal) for (city, job, sal) in v])/len(v)
    var = sum(map(lambda x: (int(x[-1]) - avg)**2, v))/len(v)
    return math.sqrt(var)

tups = []
with open("try.csv") as f:
    rdr = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n')
    for line in rdr:
        tups.append(tuple(line[0].split(',')))
tups = tups[1:]

d = {}
for (city, job, sal) in tups:
    d.setdefault(job, []).append((city, job, sal))

for k, v in d.items():
    print k, std_dev(v)
```